# Configure multiple hosts with inheritance, overriding memory

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I have a `Vagrantfile` that provisions 6 virtual machines. They are all similar, except of the necessary memory size (and the ip address).

I would like to set a default for RAM size and change it where necessary, `process1` and `process2` should get 6GB.

I tried to change `.memory` using several prefixes (app, v, ...) but obviously didn't get the syntax right.
I also tried `app.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "6144"]` but `vagrant validate` complained about this.

At present the file looks like this:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure( VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "geerlingguy/centos7"
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
    v.memory = 2048
    v.linked_clone = true
  end

  config.vm.define "process1" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "process1"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.11"
  end

  config.vm.define "process2" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "process2"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.12"
  end

  config.vm.define "index1" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "index1"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.13"
  end

  config.vm.define "index2" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "index2"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.14"
  end

  config.vm.define "quorum" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "quorum"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.15"
  end

  config.vm.define "control" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "control"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.21"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override into each block

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure( VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "geerlingguy/centos7"
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
    v.memory = 2048
    v.linked_clone = true
  end

  config.vm.define "process1" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "process1"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.11"
    app.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      v.memory = 6144
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "process2" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "process2"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.12"
    app.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      v.memory = 6144
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "index1" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "index1"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.13"
  end

  config.vm.define "index2" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "index2"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.14"
  end

  config.vm.define "quorum" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "quorum"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.15"
  end

  config.vm.define "control" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "control"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.21"
  end

end
```

Comment: I tried to set `memory = 6144` directly on the same level as `app.vm.hostname` is located. This works, does it have disadvantages over what you wrote above ?

Comment: I have to correct myself. Vagrant accepted the syntax but didn't change the memory size. Your solution is the working one.